# Using selected NSManagedObject across different controllers

Tags: core-data, persistence, xcode4.3, nsmanagedobject

I have an entity called Practice and I use a View Controller called SelectorViewController to select one of the practices, selectedPractice. I then return selectedPractice to a view Controller called RegularViewController where I display some of the selectedPractice attributes. All of this works fine. However the app has a number of other View Controllers which can be reached by modal segues from instances of RegularViewController. As a result, if I leave and then come back to RegularViewController, selectedPractice is reset as null. I would also like to save selectedPractice so that it is available at app initialisation if it has previously been set in SelectorViewController. How do I achieve this by making selectedPractice persistent across the app, and available at runtime?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the post above, which was great,  I managed to sort it. Here is my code, which may be very clumsy, but it works.

Firstly, as I loaded the fetchedObjects into a PickerView in SelectorView Controller, I set an attribute "isSelectedPractice" to "NO" with the following code:

```
for (Practice *fetchedPractice in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        [fetchedPractice setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"isSelectedPractice"];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

I then identified for the selected Practice:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    Practice *practice = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
    self.selectedPractice = practice;
    NSLog(@"The '%@' practice was selected using the picker", self.selectedPractice.name); 
}
```

as the view Segue'd back to RegularViewController I set the isSelectedPractice attribute for selectedPractice to YES. I kept it this late as I didn't want more than one selection in the PickerView to result in multiple objects with isSelectedPractice YES.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SavedPractice Segue"])
    {
        [self.selectedPractice setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"isSelectedPractice"];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        NSLog(@"Setting SelectedPractice as '%@' in RegularViewController with isSelectedPractice as '%@'",self.selectedPractice.name,self.selectedPractice.isSelectedPractice );
        RegularViewController *rvc= segue.destinationViewController;
        rvc.delegate = self;
        rvc.selectedPractice = self.selectedPractice;

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}
```

I then set the following Predicate in the setupFetchedResultsController method of RegularViewController:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelectedPractice = %@", @"YES"];
```

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual project, one way I know will work but might be a little too round a bout would be to add an attribute "isSelectedPractice" to your entity. You could make it a BOOL, but I've had mixed results with BOOL's in Core Data, I prefer to just leave it as a NSString and set it to "yes" or "no".  Then when you pull it down, modify it or add it to core Data as a entity with isSelectedPractice set to "yes". Then in your other controllers, do a

```
if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

then do a fetch request to get entities with a predicate which is looking for isSelectedPractice equaling "yes". If you need actual code samples on how to do this let me know and I'll edit them in.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about using an attribute and you've just confirmed it. How does SetValue: ForKey: get applied to selectedPractice in a method?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain in a little more detail what you mean?